# Beginning programming: Simple/Quick work log application

Tags: windows

I want to create a simple work log program/script with very basic function. Basically when I run it I want it to prompt me with an input windows. When I write the input it prints it into a .txt file with the current date and time.

```
Input : <text here>
```

and the output would look something like this in a .txt file.

```
<HH:MM:SS YYYY:MM:DD> | <text here>
```

What programming language is "easiest" for this kind of a program ?

With regards,

H

Comment: Windows Notepad will already do this if you type a [.Log heading](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/909/windows-notepad-insert-time-and-date-into-text-or-log-file/) in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well I think your question is going to be a bit difficult to answer head on. How about asking yourself what language you do know. If you don't know any, then take the problem you are trying to solve each step at a time with documentation that your comfortable with. Do you want a program that strictly uses the command line? Or do you want a program with a GUI? That being said, I preferably would recommend Java because I think the syntax is more clear to me, but someone might recommend, say language X because they might know a few easier tricks. So my advice is, do some more research into a programming language and come back with more of a precise question that relates to the results your looking for.